# Mysql automated date field, syntax errors

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a mysql table which contains two fields that are automatically given the current date when data is first put into them

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`characters` (
  `character_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ckey` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `character_name` VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
  `birth` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_seen` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`character_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `character_id_UNIQUE` (`character_id` ASC) VISIBLE)
```

this is not working, i get invalid default value error, which is progress
Everything else i've tried throws error 1064, sql syntax

In place of current timestamp I have tried...
GET_DATE()
GET_DATE
GETDATE
CURDATE
CURDATE()
CURRENT_DATE
CURRENT_DATE()

All of these are throwing the same syntax error, there is no error if i remove the default value.

I am almost entirely clueless about database code, this is a real newbie project, any help would be appreciated

Comment: `DATE` datatype cannot have default value other than a literal. `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is applicable to DATETIME and TIMESTAMP only.

Comment: oh, that would explain it. Well i could use datetime then
how would i get a "right now" value for datetime?

Comment: @Nanako when you insert data in table then no need to set value for birth and last_seen. The database will will current date("right_now") time and put there.

Comment: `character_id_UNIQUE` index is excess and must be removed. There is no reason for two index copies extince. PRIMARY KEY provides uniqueness itself.

Comment: `last_seen` should be `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use datetime instead of date.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `characters` (
  `character_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ckey` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `character_name` VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
  `birth` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_seen` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`character_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `character_id_UNIQUE` (`character_id` ASC) VISIBLE)
```